# Consulta select me devuelva una cadena separada por comas

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando que de una consulta select de dos tablas relacionas, me salga una salida como esta:

```
 Comidas             | Ingredientes
 Salteado de pollo   Pollo, calabacin, queso
 Macarrones          macarrones, tomate
```

Y lo que me sale es esto:

```
 Comidas             | Ingredientes
 Salteado de pollo   Pollo
 Salteado de pollo   Calabacin
 Salteado de pollo   Queso
 Macarrones          macarrones
 Macarrones          tomate
```

Esta es la estructura de la DB

ESTRUCTURA

```
CREATE TABLE `comidas` (
  `id_comida` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `receta` varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
  `calorias` float NOT NULL,
  `imagen` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `comidas_ingredientes` (
  `id_comidas_ingredientes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_ingrediente` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_comida` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `peso` float DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `ingredientes` (
  `id_ingrediente` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `calorias` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

DATOS

Estoy intentando traer los nombres de cada ingrediente pero no encuentro la forma de regresarla como una cadena de nombres

```
SELECT comidas.nombre, ingredientes.nombre from comidas
join comidas_ingredientes USING(id_comida)
join ingredientes USING(id_ingrediente)
```

Pero sinceramente no se como decirle a la DB que la traiga como una cadena delimitada por ","

Comment: Saludos. Revisa `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: Es necesario probar que necesita algo, si es una función que desconoce ???  `Pero sinceramente no se como decirle a la DB que la traiga como una cadena delimitada por ","`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te mencionan anteriormente, `GROUP_CONCAT` es la función que buscas.
Esta retorna información concatenada de 
valores no nulos (vamos que si están vacíos no los puede traer) 

Para usarlo, haces el group_concat en la selección deseada,
y agrupas por la columna principal 
En tu caso sería:

```
SELECT comidas.nombre, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(ingredientes.nombre)
FROM comidas
JOIN comidas_ingredientes USING(id_comida)
JOIN ingredientes USING(id_ingrediente)
GROUP BY comidas.nombre
```

---

En este caso, realmente desconozco si debes agregar al group_by
ambas selecciones de columnas, pero prueba en caso de...

```
GROUP BY comidas.nombre, ingredientes.nombre
```

---

Tengo que agregar la documentación, por que quien la había agregado borró el comentario.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: `En este caso, realmente desconozco si debes agregar al group_by`

Comment: Se la tendré que agregar donde se la borraste...